# Локализация(автоматический перевод) string-array, в Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, android-sdk, android-studio

Как можно автоматически переводить строковые массивы с помощью Translation Editor?

Есть несколько одиночных элементов, которые не состоят в массиве, а массивы нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так выглядит файл ресурсов:

    Explain It

```
<string name="food">Food</string>
<string name="clothes">Clothes</string>
<string name="math">Math</string>
<string name="science">Science</string>

<string-array name="food">
    <item>Noisettes</item>
    <item>Apple</item>
    <item>Pelmeni</item>
    <item>Pineaple</item>
    <item>Cabbage</item>
    <item>Squash</item>
    <item>Orange</item>
    <item>Lemon</item>
    <item>Jelly</item>
    <item>Honney</item>
    <item>Sausage</item>
    <item>Pizza</item>
    <item>Onion</item>
    <item>Lemonade</item>
    <item>Tea</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="math">
    <item>Arabic number</item>
    <item>Integral</item>
    <item>Square root</item>
    <item>Add</item>
    <item>Minus</item>
    <item>Remainder</item>
    <item>Float number</item>
    <item>Integer</item>
    <item>Function</item>
    <item>Divide</item>
    <item>Variable</item>
    <item>Constant</item>
    <item>Zero</item>
    <item>Infinity</item>
    <item>Limit</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="science">
    <item>Atom</item>
    <item>Molecule</item>
    <item>Star</item>
    <item>Planet</item>
    <item>Plasma</item>
    <item>E=mc2</item>
    <item>Newton</item>
    <item>Sphere</item>
    <item>Rainbow</item>
    <item>Big bang</item>
    <item>Black hole</item>
    <item>Singularity</item>
    <item>Sound waves</item>
    <item>Light speed</item>
    <item>Eddison`s lamp</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [ссылке](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75303) на баг-треккер гугла поддержки перевода массивов строк пока нет. (в декабре 15 всё ещё просят это поправить).

Там же [предлагают](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75303#c5) обойти это задав элементам строкового массива значения в виде ссылок на другие строки. Т.е. сделайте по отдельной строке для каждого элемента массива и укажите их в массиве так:

```
<string name="ten">ten</string>
<string name="twenty">twenty</string>
<string name="thirty">thirty</string>

<string-array name="testarray">
     <item>@string/ten</item>
     <item>@string/twenty</item>
     <item>@string/thirty</item>
</string-array>
```

**Будьте внимательны** - там же [говорят](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=75303#c10), что это не поможет, если использовать сторонний софт пре перевода (не `Translation Editor`)